# download multiple files which were last uploaded or today uploaded files from s3 bucket using python code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, devops

I am trying to download multiple files which were last uploaded or today uploaded files from s3 bucket using python code. Using below code do not want all the files to be downloaded ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto
import sys, os
from boto.s3.key import Key
from boto.exception import S3ResponseError

DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH = os.path.expanduser("~") + "/s3-backup/"
if not os.path.exists(DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH):
    print ("Making download directory")
    os.mkdir(DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH)


def backup_s3_folder():
    BUCKET_NAME = "xxxx"
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= os.getenv("xxxxx") # set your AWS_KEY_ID  on your environment path
    AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("xxxxxx") # set your AWS_ACCESS_KEY  on your environment path
    conn  = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

    #goto through the list of files
    bucket_list = bucket.list()

    for l in bucket_list:
        key_string = str(l.key)
        s3_path = DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH + key_string
        try:
            print ("Current File is ", s3_path)
            l.get_contents_to_filename(s3_path)
        except (OSError,S3ResponseError) as e:
            pass
            # check if the file has been downloaded locally
            if not os.path.exists(s3_path):
                try:
                    os.makedirs(s3_path)
                except OSError as exc:
                    # let guard againts race conditions
                    import errno
                    if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                        raise
if __name__ == '__main__':
    backup_s3_folder()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. By selecting a block of text and clicking the "Code Sample" button (looks like this `{}`) you can mark the entire block as being code and it will be formated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you want to retrieve only the files that were uploaded "today" and by today i mean the same day this code is executed according to the date time on the os. You can achieve this by adding a conditional on the foreach statement to evaluate the last modified attribute from each element, so it would go something along these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto
import sys, os
from boto.s3.key import Key
from boto.exception import S3ResponseError

#Get today's date
date_today = datetime.datetime.today().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH = os.path.expanduser("~") + "/s3-backup/"
if not os.path.exists(DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH):
    print ("Making download directory")
    os.mkdir(DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH)
def backup_s3_folder():
    BUCKET_NAME = "xxxx"
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= os.getenv("xxxxx") # set your AWS_KEY_ID  on your environment path
    AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("xxxxxx") # set your AWS_ACCESS_KEY  on your environment path
    conn  = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

    #goto through the list of files
    bucket_list = bucket.list()

    for l in bucket_list:
        key_string = str(l.key)
        s3_path = DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH + key_string
        try:
            if boto.utils.parse_ts(l.last_modified) >  date_today:
                print ("Current File is ", s3_path)
                l.get_contents_to_filename(s3_path)
        except (OSError,S3ResponseError) as e:
            pass
            # check if the file has been downloaded locally
            if not os.path.exists(s3_path):
                try:
                    os.makedirs(s3_path)
                except OSError as exc:
                    # let guard againts race conditions
                    import errno
                    if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                        raise
if __name__ == '__main__':
    backup_s3_folder()
```

All this does is getting today's date at midnight and checking if the s3 file's last modified attribute is greater than that (so the file was uploaded/modified "today").

Bear in mind that you probably would need to do some handling with the timezone when you retrieve the last modified attribute, be sure that you convert it to the same timezone that the system running this script is on!